# How to get client Mac to use caching facility from Mac OS X Server on Yosemite

Tags: macos, server.app

I have installed Mac OSX server onto one machine. Caching is enabled.

How do I now configure a client Mac on the same network to start using this cache for both web browsing and software updates?

I have tried System Preferences -> Network -> Advanced -> Proxies and enabled "Web Proxy (HTTP)" and entered the local IP of the machine running Mac OSX Server (192.168.1.24) and the port number 49524 but this doesn't work. I just see a blank white screen when I try and view any web page in Chrome.

Does anybody know the correct set up instructions for the clients? There appears to be very little to help me out on Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Caching service* is no web-proxy. It just provides software updates, purchased apps from the Mac App Store, iBooks and iTunes U content.

When you first enable the caching server, it registers its public IP and private IP with Apple.  If a client tries to download a software update or an app from the same public IP as the server, Apple “introduces” the client to the server automatically. Therefore client configuration is not required.

If you want a proxy server install [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/)/[Squidman](http://squidman.net/squidman/)

Comment: That means caching will not work if web-proxies are enabled. Then what is recommended to store updates in server?

Comment: @Nagarjun Caching (as in Apple's Caching Server) should still work even if you use a web-proxy. The person asking just tried to use the Caching Server **as** a web-proxy - which doesn't work.

Comment: i tried enabling caching in osx but nothing is storing in mac disk. What i did is i installed caching in one of my Mac and started downloading apps using appstore also i tried downloading updates but nothing works fine. But i use Both Web proxy and secure web proxy enabled. Am i doing anything wrong ? I have connected these mac machines using Ethernet which my company provides.

Comment: @Nagarjun Did you install and configure an OS X Server.app?

Comment: Yes some how it started working now.

Comment: Could someone please comment if DHCP service on OS X Server should be enabled for this to work? I assume from these answers and documentation that it shouldn't be required, but could someone please confirm?

Comment: @Chris IMHO DHCP doesn't have to be enabled. Multicast DNS (mDNS) & DNS Service Discovery (DNS-SD) has to work though. You may check this with `dns-sd -B _aaplcache._tcp local`.

Comment: Is it possible that App Updates are not usually cached (even though that would contradict Apple's documentation)? Especially since "App Thinning" was introduced.

Answer (score 2):

It is to a point transparent.  Here is a good quote from the Apple article about caching server

**"and by default is configured to support clients that share the same public IP address behind a NAT."**

As long as you have your clients set up behind the same NAT it will download from Apple for the first download and every client after that will then download form the Caching server.  Take a look at the picture below from Apple's documentation.  So in the end their is no client side setup needed if your network is setup correctly.

[Apple Link](http://help.apple.com/serverapp/mac/4.0/#/apd74DDE89F-08D2-4E0A-A5CD-155E345EFB83)

[image]

Comment: thank you for the reply. This is odd. The IP of my server is 192.168.1.24. My client is 192.168.1.28. They are on the same network and I've left the network proxy settings empty (default). Browsing the internet works but nothing is being shown on the "Caching" section of the server.

Comment: Sorry, I must have confused your article.  Caching server has nothing to do with browsing the internet.  Its purpose is for Mac app store downloads and updates.  I think your looking for something else if internet browser caching is what your after.

Comment: My understanding was that "Caching" was for web browsing and the separate menu option called "Software Update" (under the advanced menu) was for the downloads/updates. I am keen to achieve both.

Comment: No.  Read the article I linked above from Apple.  The software Update under advanced is a whole different server applet.